# Client: Lightwieght communication protocol for linux

Tags: linux, client-server, client, xmpp, mqtt

I want to use a communication mechanism between a server and a linux client, for messaging and discovery. My only requirement is that, the client should be as lightweight as possible. On searching internet, I cam across XMPP and MQTT. But, I am not sure, which of its version is the most lightweight. Can anybody please guide me regarding which is the most lightweight of all. Please let me know, if any other such mechanism exists.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an easy question, because it's not clear which aspects of "lightweightness" you are looking for. Are you looking for small implementation (in file size), for minimum CPU usage or minimum network requirements.

MQTT and XMPP can both be pretty slim on the client side. Out of the box without any extensions, MQTT most of the time is (much) more lightweight on the wire, it's a binary protocol while XMPP is (without any extensions) XML based. MQTT focuses on efficient Pub/Sub messaging, if you need something fancy on top, you should choose a sophisticated broker ([click here for an overview](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/Server%20support)). XMPP has a bit more out of the box. If you don't need things like friendship requests on the protocol level, MQTT is a solid choice.

Again, both protocols have their use cases (which IMHO don't intersect too much). A pretty good overview of MQTT, XMPP, CoAP and HTTP can be [found here on slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/goetzchr/how-dothingstalkio-texpo2014).